# Google Sheets how to reference one cell based on another cell

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I am working on a nutrition spreadsheet.
The columns (in row 13) are 'Calories' 'Carbs' 'Protein' and 'Fat'.
Under each of those cells (in row 13) are values that change.
Im trying to come up with a formula that searches for the maximum value in row 13 and returns the cell reference of the cell above it.

Ive tried combinations of:
lookup
hlookup
match
max
address
index
cell

Some times it would return 'Fat' when the Calorie column had the max value.
Other times it would say it couldn't find a value within the array, that was clearly there...

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: @player0 I'm sorry, stack overflow comments/posts require coding skills (for what should be fairly simple formatting things) that are way above my abilities. I've tried before to figure out how to do it, but it never turns out how I want and takes WAY too long...

Comment: @player0 basically Cells B13:E13 say Calories, Carbs, Protein, Fat. Cells B14:E14 have values that change. I want to search B14:E14 for the max value and return either 'Calories' or B13 (if that value is the max).  I plan on using that result to search a specific range in a separate table for the highest value closest to the max number in B14:E14 (which I will figure out later how to do)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Index(,,Match(Max(),,))